# Pusher error: The data content of this event exceeds the allowed maximum (10240 bytes)

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm working on a project where I want to live display users' points whenever the gain or lose points.

I have an api that sends event to the frontend:

```
    public function test(Request $request){
        $message = $request->message;
        $users = User::all()->where('company_id', $message);
        event(new MyEvent([$users]));
    }
```

Whenever the api is called, I recieve the following error:

Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException: Pusher error: The data content of this event exceeds the allowed maximum (10240 bytes).

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is to reduce the payload size - Pusher has a size limit on the body of an event - https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/rest-api/#post-event-trigger-an-event

They also list some strategies for reducing payload size, such as:

- sending multiple small events instead one one large event (chunking)
- using compression to reduce payload size
- sending a link the client that downloads the content instead of transmitting it via Channels.

See https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412243423761-What-Is-The-Message-Size-Limit-When-Publishing-an-Event-in-Channels- for more info

Answer (score 4):

Source: https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412243423761-What-Is-The-Message-Size-Limit-When-Publishing-an-Event-in-Channels-

The message size limit is 10KB.

There are several approaches to work around this limit:

1. Chunking. One approach is to split your large message into smaller
   chunks before publishing, then recombine them on receipt. This
   repository shows an example of a chunking protocol: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-channels-chunking-example.
2. Linking. Instead of sending a large message via Pusher Channels, you could store that message elsewhere, and just send your clients send a link to that content.
3. Compression, e.g.

   - Compression algorithms like gzip.
   - Removing unnecessary characters. Whitespace is one example.
   - Removing/shortening keys. Instead of {"user":"jim","email":"jim@example.com"}, you could use {"u":"jim","e":"jim@example.com"}, or ["jim","jim@example.com"].
4. A dedicated cluster. If none of the above are suitable and you really need to sender larger single messages, we can set up a dedicated cluster. If you are interested in provisioning a dedicated cluster as part of an enterprise package please contact Pusher sales.